# Whenever I creating a new project, the xcode window will disapper

Tags: iphone, xcode

Whenever I creating a new project, the xcode(4.2) downloaded from MacStore, the xcode window will disapper in os x lion

and when I open any project, it will displaying me this window!

Answer (score 0):

I can't really tell what the problem might be from your question, other than perhaps XCode is crashing. If Xcode is no longer running after this, then it's crashing. Completely uninstall XCode and re-download and install it.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GOB3P2XzmiI&v=GOB3P2XzmiI&gl=US

Comment: There are other places online with instructions for uninstalling XCode if that one didn't work for you - just Google for uninstall xcode. I had to reinstall it once, too.